# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound ([404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

Not sure while working in local environment with `elasticsearch` i m getting this weird error, any help would me appreciated. thanks

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound ([404]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
>   such
>   index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"invoices","index":"invoices"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
>   such
>   index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"invoices","index":"invoices"},"status":404})

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing exactly? The error simply says that the `invoices` index you're hitting does not exist in your local ES server.

Comment: @Val hi thanks for your reply, actually elastic search has been used in my existing project and its working fine everywhere but not in case of `invoice` model and i'm new for elastic search. i have updated the question with controller code, can you please have a look there.

Comment: What this tells me is simply that you don't have any data in your local server. Did you forgot to create your index and load your data first maybe?

Comment: @Val i have 5 records in invoices tables. and not sure about index things.

Comment: What do you mean by "table". Elasticsearch doesn't have any tables, but it has indexes. Do you have data in a database that is supposedly synched with your Elasticsearch server?

Comment: @Val do you mean that i'will have to indexing columns of invoices table before apply search method.?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. How does your project work in general?

Comment: @Val project is kind of eCommerce. and one more thing i have to ask, do i need to indexing the all column names by which i want to search, suppose i have 5 column name and i wan to search with only 2 or 3 column then do i need to apply indexing on those 2 or 3 columns? am i right?

Comment: Basically, you only need to index into ES what you expect to search on. But if you also expect to retrieve fields that you do not search on, then you should also store them inside ES.

Comment: @Val Hi thnaks, i have created index and its working find. can you give me some references for elastic search as i'm new in this also i m from ruby on rails background.

Comment: I would start with the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/ruby-api/current/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed issue by indexing ES by running these commands at `rails console`: -

```
Model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
Model.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
Model.import force: true
```

Comment: all you need is `Model.import(force: true)` - that will create the index and then do the import

Comment: This solved the error I get which is similar or maybe same with OP. But those lines are already in rails_helper.rb, what should I do to not to run them manually but instead have it automatically working?

Comment: @CalebKeene That wasn't true for me. It gave me an error. It looked like it was trying to drop an index that didn't exist and having a problem if this is the first time you are ever creating that index.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow this steps i find on [rubydoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-rails) website :

require the task definition in your application, eg. in the lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake file:

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

To import the records from your model, run:

```
bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='ModelName'
```

Or you can use:

```
rake environment elasticsearch:import:all DIR=app/models
```

to import all models.